# Windows XP don't show login screen after opening laptop lid

Tags: windows-xp, sleep, dell-latitude, suspend

On my Dell Latitude D530 with Windows XP, I closed the lid and I think I opened it before the computer went into sleep mode. When I opened the lid, the login screen didn't show up! No menu, nothing. Only empty desktop - so I cannot actually log in and do anything! Ctrl-Alt-Del doesn't do anything. System is alive, Caps-Lock turns on/off the led, mouse cursor moves, but the right click doesn't do anything.

I have many applications open with unsaved data. What can I do now? Is there any way for example to force hybernation? Closing the lid and opening again won't help - the computer is still awake, will not actually go into sleep mode.

**Result:** as advised in the comments below, as neither Win+R nor Win+L worked, I tried the last resort - let it run out of battery - with the closed lid. Unfortunatelly the system was not hybernated, so I lost all the unsaved data :-(

Comment: Can you see a run box when you press Win+R?

Comment: @dx486 unfortunatelly not...

Comment: I guess Win+L does not work either? If not, it seems you cannot give any command via keyboard, which means there is nothing to do. Maybe you can try to remove power cord, and close the lid. That way, battery power scheme may cause your computer to sleep properly.

Comment: @dx486 Win+L doesn't work either :( Yes, this was my idea as well, I tried it for some time and I got the warning alert telling me that the battery is almost out and I should  plug in the power cord, but nothing happened in next 15 minutes. So I am afraid that the hybernation won't be triggered, despite it normally works.

Comment: @dx486, is it better to close the lid after unplugging the cord, or keep it open? In which case do I actually have more chance to get hybernation? Sleep won't happen.

Comment: Before battery runs out, XP should save everything in the memory to disk to prevent data loss, then shuts computer down (hibernate). I would try that as a last resort, but I am not sure if this will work in your system. Before going that way, maybe you can try to plug in an external keyboard but I guess it would not help.

Comment: @dx486 that would not help - the keyboard is working (the caps lock, num lock etc. change the leds). So, is it better to keep the lid open or close it? My intuition tells me that it is better to keep it open, sometimes the Dell didn't hybernate when it was closed.

Comment: Running on battery and close lid are two common conditions for quick sleep/hibernation. It depends on the power settings of your computer really. Your system is unstable now, so we cannot be sure if it will work as expected. If you are not sure I think it is better to close the lid for higher probabality to start sleep/hibernation process sooner.

Comment: @dx486 I will try it, thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Please tell us the result.

Comment: @dx486 the result is bad, please see the update :-( Thank you for your help though!

Comment: I am sorry @Tomas. From now on please enable auto save feature of your software. BTW for better stability you may consider switching to a stable GNU/Linux distribution too. XP is outdated.

Comment: @dx486 thanks. I use software like Notepad or [R](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/), it has no autosave feature unfortunatelly... Or do you know how to have Notepad with autosave? I posted a new question on that: http://superuser.com/q/842119/93604